# Passing session variables to another page

Tags: php, session, mysqli

I am trying to pass session variable to the next page, index.php but i have gotten an error undefined index on `foreach($_SESSION['result'] as $row)`. May i know what's wrong?

```
<?php
session_start();
$search = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/", " ", $_POST['query']);
$search = $db->real_escape_string($search);

if (strlen($search) >= 1 && $search !== ' ') {
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE name LIKE "%'.$search.'%"';
    $result = $db->query($query) or trigger_error($db->error."[$query]");


    while($results = $result->fetch_array()) {
        $resultArray[] = $results;
    }   

    if (isset($resultArray)) {
        foreach ($resultArray as $result) {
            $show_name = preg_replace("/".$search."/i", "<b class='highlight'>".$search."</b>", $result['name']);
            $show_url = 'index.php';
            $out = str_replace('name', $show_name, $html);
            $out = str_replace('url', $show_url, $out); 
            $_SESSION['result']= $result['name'];
            echo($out);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

## index.php

```
session_start();
<table>
<?php foreach($_SESSION['result'] as $row){ ?>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <?php echo $row['name'];?>
              </td>
              <td>
                <?php echo $row['description'];?>
              </td>
            </tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: You've just edited your post to add what I recommended in my answer.  Please don't change your question to implement a solution!  This makes the solution invalid and makes it impossible for people who come later to see your mistakes and learn from them, or to give proper credit to good answers.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: result and 
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: sorry but I did had session_start(). It's just that i forgot to write it here

Comment: $row['description'] is from the table

Answer (score 0):

You never start the session in the first file.  Start the file with

```
<?php    
session_start();
```

Because you're missing that, when you assign a value to `$_SESSION['result']` after your queries, nothing is saved in session.

There is another error. You mean for `$_SESSION['result']` to be an array, but you're saving it as a string.  Change:

```
$_SESSION['result']= $result['name'];
```

To

```
$_SESSION['result'][]= $result['name'];
```

Comment: sorry i did not write it here, i did have session start but the errors keep coming:

Notice: Undefined index: result and
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Please test again, from the beginning. After you've put session start at the top of the first file, execute that file first and make sure the queries are run properly.  Then load the second file again.  The error should go away.

Comment: then from my index.php, do I have to add 

<?php foreach($_SESSION['search_output'][] as $row){ ?>

Answer (score 0):

if $_SESSION['result'] is an array then try like below

```
$_SESSION['result'][]= $result['name'];
```

as per your code session result variable is not an array

Comment: then from my index.php, do I have to add 

<?php foreach($_SESSION['search_output'][] as $row){ ?>

Comment: in index.php tyrr to print_r($_SESSION['results']), what the output comes

Comment: Try this one :foreach ($_SESSION as $key => $value) {
  echo $value['name'];
}

Comment: Array ( [0] => final year project [1] => internship [2] => internship 2 [3] => final year project [4] => internship [5] => internship 2 [6] => internship [7] => internship 2 [8] => internship [9] => internship 2 [10] => internship [11] => internship 2 [12] => internship [13] => internship 2)....

Comment: Try : foreach ($_SESSION as $key => $value) { echo $value; }

Comment: I tried and this works for me, try it foreach($_SESSION['result'] as $value){
 echo $value;
}

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() :(